# Parsing data into an ArrayList. Collects Data fine, doesn't parse

Tags: android, json, parsing, arraylist

getting close to the goal I want. I've got a URL with json on it. I want to parse that JSON into an ArrayList, or anyway that I can get into into some TextViews and one ImageView. Right now I've gone down the ArrayList route.

The JSON gets collected from the URL just fine and I have it show up in my logcat, no issues there. The issue is when it comes to parsing it. There's a high chance I'm doing this inefficiently but yeah...

Here's my code:

```
public class BookDetails extends Activity {

JSONArray jArray;
String result = "";
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb = null;
String url;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.book_details);
    new HttpTask().execute();
    
    Intent in = getIntent();
    url = in.getStringExtra("jsonUrl");
    
    if (url == null) {
        Log.d("NOT_SENT", "It's not working.. url empty");
    }
    else {
        Log.d("SENT", "ITS WORKING");
    }
    
}

//JSON CLASS
public class Books {
    
    public String book1;
    public String book2;
    public String book3;
    public String book4;
    public String book5;
    public String image;
    
    public Books(String _bookone, String _booktwo, String _bookthree, 
                         String_bookfour, String _bookfive, String _image) {
        book1 = _bookone;
        price = _booktwo;
        id = _bookthree;
        title = _bookfour;
        link = _bookfive;
        image = _image;
    }
}

public class HttpTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Books>> {
    
    //Do on pre exceute before shipping
    
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Books> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    
        //Post request
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpGet.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/json"));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            
            is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("REST SERVICE", "Error in post request!");
        }
        
        //Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.i("JSON_STRING", result);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE_STRING", "The data could not be converted");
        }
        
        //Parse the JSON data
        ArrayList<Books> bookData = null;
        JSONObject json_data;
        Books b;
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                
                b = new Books(json_data.getString("bookone"),
                                 json_data.getString("booktwo"),
                                 json_data.getString("bookthree"),
                                 json_data.getString("bookfour"),
                                 json_data.getString("bookfive"),
                                 json_data.getString("image"));
                bookData.add(b);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException je) {
            Log.d("JSON_PARSE", "Error in parsing data");
        }
        
        return bookData;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Books> bookData) {
        super.onPostExecute(bookData);
        //Log.i("IS_DATA_THERE", bookData.get(0).bookone);
        
        String firstDataTest = bookData.get(0).bookone;
        
        TextView testtest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTest);
        testtest.setText(firstDataTest);
    }
    
}

}
```

When the code gets down to bookData.add(b) I'm getting a warning telling me that bookData can only be null at this point. How when I just added the json_data to it...?

My JSON:

```
{
"bookone": "namehere",
"booktwo": 50.99,
"image": ". "jpg url",
"bookthree": "2020",
"bookfour": "2020",
"bookfive": "namehere"
}
```

Sometimes bookfour is a 'namehere' as well.

Hopefully you guys can help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

B'coz you did't initialise the ArrayList
Replace

```
ArrayList<Books> bookData = null;
```

with

```
ArrayList<Books> bookData = new ArrayList<Books>();
```

Hope this works.

Comment: That got rid of the bookdata being empty but now I'm getting an error that says "Invalid index 0, size is 0;" Before that the log gets activated "Error in parsing data".

Comment: @RED_ can you post json string?

Comment: @RED_ its a array or simple JsonObject? As you posted json string is not an array.

Comment: Ah... I have many links to parse and they all have one JSONObject to parse. So using the ArrayList is simply wrong? What's the alternative in getting this working? Should I replace JSONArray with JSONObject?